# Rename the filename with the title while copying them

Tags: php

I wanna rename the filename of documents that I get from crawl a web using simple_html_dom. here's my whole code:

```
foreach($html->find('h3[class=gs_rt] a') as $link1){
    foreach($link1->parent()->parent()->parent()->find('div[class=gs_ggs gs_fl]') as $link2){
        $docLink = $link2->first_child();
        if(strtolower(substr($docLink->href, strrpos($docLink->href, '.'))) === '.pdf') {
            $title   = strip_tags($link1->plaintext);
            $webLink = strip_tags($link1->href);
            $pdfLink = strip_tags($docLink->href);
            copy($pdfLink, $savePath . basename($pdfLink));
        }
    }
}
```

I wanna rename filename with the title in this line :

```
copy($pdfLink, $title));
```

But. it does not work, what's wrong ? please help me

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to create an object out of $link2 before you can access its properties.

Comment: can you give me an example ? Using my code I've gotten correct `$title` and correct `$pdfLink`